# Does the QNetworkAccessManager destructor abort the current requests?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

Working on an application where the user should be able to cancel all the uploads. Now I wonder if I have to hunt down all the replies from the QNAM or just delete it and expect them all to abort then?

There's nothing in the doc stating anything about aborting but I'm assuming that it will.

> Destroys the QNetworkAccessManager object and frees up any resources. Note that QNetworkReply objects that are returned from this class have this object set as their parents, which means that they will be deleted along with it if you don't call QObject::setParent() on them.

EDIT:
Ended up using a wrapper for every reply (which also takes ownership over it and does retrys etc) which in its destructor both disconnects the QNetworkReplys signals aswell as abort it. The it gets deleted along with the wrapper (parent->child)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will just delete the replies. From the source:

```
QNetworkAccessManager::~QNetworkAccessManager()
{
    // ...

    qDeleteAll(findChildren<QNetworkReply *>());

    // ...
}
```

And the destructor of QNetworkReply is empty, so you need to abort them manually.

Comment: yeah im fully aware of that hence stated in the doc. but i was more wondering about if i had to abort() all the replies (canceling all uploads) before deleting the QNAM?

Comment: @chikuba There's nothing in the source of the QNetworkReply destructor that calls `abort()`.

Comment: @chikuba - Well, yes, because otherwise you're going to have and be trying to use pointers that are no longer valid. Hello undefined behavior.

Comment: so what happens to requests that are up and going when I delete?

Comment: @chikuba That I don't know... test it and see?

Comment: it seems to be aborted which it it would since im deleteing the QNAM in the same go

Comment: Hi again. just noticed this in the documentation on the reply-destructor "    Disposes of this reply and frees any resources associated with
    it. If any network connections are still open, they will be
    closed.

    \sa abort(), close()"